# Post method won't work in advanced search

Tags: post, get, yii

I changed `'method'=>'get'` to `'method'=>'POST'` in category _search page. when i go to the category/admin and advanced search and search category, i see searched item in url and i see **GET** instead of **POST** method in firebug. 
why?

Comment: It's an ajaxy search, so why does it matter anyways?

Comment: i dont use ajaxy search beacause some column dont load on ajax load. i dont use get beacause i have a problem with long get request and apache error.

Comment: So did you modify the advanced search to refresh the page? Did you remove the `ajaxSubmit` button as well? If you did, check the rendered HTML if the form's method really is `post`. You may have a typo in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in yii forum [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33236-post-method-wont-work-in-advanced-search/).